# What is the basis of named colors on the web?

Tags: css, colors

We have color codes, for example: `#ffffff` or `#000000` or `#71ac41`.

The color code is based on an algorithm, but how is it achieved?
I'm seeing an article here that says the Color Code is calculated based on hex value:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colorsfull.asp

But my question is how? 
Can anyone show me an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what others have said, here is an image that might help you understand:

[image: Hex colours]

Much more information [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/04/the-code-side-of-color/).

Answer (score 1):

Every pair of characters represents a base color, ranging from **00** to **FF** in hexadecimal, or **0** to **225** in decimal.

Since we are using RGB (meaning Red Green Blue), the color #71ac41 can be parted as:

```
Red: 71 (hexadecimal) = 113 (decimal)
Green: ac (hexadecimal) = 172 (decimal)
Blue: 41 (hexadecimal) = 65 (decimal)
```

So we have 113/225 in Red, 172/225 in Green and 65/225 in Blue.

The chromatic sum of each of those three numbers, each ranging from 0 to 225 in decimal, makes the color you get.

In this website you can insert any color in that format and get detailed information about it's construction: http://www.color-hex.com/color/71ac41

Answer (score 1):

There are two format RGB and ARGB. RGB means red, green, blue. And ARGB stand for Alpha,red, green, blue. each have 0 to 255 (in decimal format) or 00 to ff (in hex format) values and we used it in hex format like #000000 in RGB or #00ffffff in ARGB.

first two zero define red, second two zero define green and remain define blue. And in ARGB first two zero define alpha and remain define as RGB.

Answer (score 1):

The colors are specified according to their intensity in **red, green and blue** each represented by eight bits, a byte. Each byte can be represented as two hexadecimal digits, that's why there are six digits in the canonical hex code of the color. If you convert these bits in hexadecimal form and put the `#` in the beginning you then get the hexadecimal code of the color e.g. `#FFFFFF`.

Further reading:

[Web colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)

[Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)